# Java script check exclude each value of array if this value is equal to specific attribute of array of objects

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, filter

**i have tow array for tow drop down list,and i need to exclude the selected value from the list each time.
but it does not work**

```
arr1 = [{label: "Syria",value: 1},{label: "USA",value: 2}]
arr2 = [{country:1}]

excludeSelectedCountry() {
  if ( arr1.length > 0) {
    return arr1.filter(
      country =>
        !arr2.some(e => {
          e.country && e.country === country.value;
        })
    );
  } else return arr2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
let arr1=[{label: "Syria",value: 1},{label: "USA",value: 2}];
let arr2=[{country:1}];

const excludeSelectedCountry = () => {
     if (arr1.length > 0) {
          return arr1.filter(country => !arr2.find(e => e.country==country.value));
     } else {
          return arr2;
     }
}

console.log( excludeSelectedCountry() );
```